# Reload the data of the table when there is a change in Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a basic CRUD page with vuejs + laravel. I open 2 tabs: 1 tab is list page and 1 tab is creation page. When I add a new record on the create page, how does the list page automatically reload newly added data without reloading the page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show data automatically without refresh with vue.js laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57916789/how-to-show-data-automatically-without-refresh-with-vue-js-laravel)

Comment: not it :(, it reloads the list after adding new on the same tab. I want the list in another tab to reload itself.

Comment: The page showing the list will also reload when I have no impact on it

Comment: You could use `websocket` to stream the change message and then have the UI update the view.

Answer (score 0):

If you made it with MongoDB you can use "change streams

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/

You could combine it with socket.io. Whenever your data in your database change you send an socket.io event with the data thats added, deleted or updated to your client, your vue app

An other way would be to have an `setInterval` to update your data in vue.js for example every 5 seconds.